# Python: display multiple values in a column for a single value in another column

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly, seaborn

I have a pandas dataframe with three columns

```
data = np.array([[0,'Time',27.390000],
                [0,'Score',0.027585],
                [1,'Time',47.390000],
                [1,'Score',0.23776],
                [2,'Time',65.390000],
                [2,'Score',0.44776]])
data = pd.DataFrame(data)
data.columns = ['Rounds','Metrics','WA_All_par_1']
data["WA_All_par_1"] = pd.to_numeric(data["WA_All_par_1"])
data

    Rounds   Metrics    WA_All_par_1
1   0        Time       27.390000
2   0        Score      0.027585
3   1        Time       47.390000
4   1        Score      0.23776
5   2        Time       65.390000
6   2        Score      0.44776
```

I want to plot rounds on X axis (for every round there are 2 metrics) and Metrics on y axis and I want to show score and time as the rounds increase

I tried

```
data.set_index('Rounds').plot(figsize=(8,5), grid=True)
```

[image]

I want to show score and Time with different colors in histograms.

Comment: Do you want  plot one for time and one for score with different colors in the same plot?

Comment: not separate plots but both metrics(Time and score) side by side for one round

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

try:

```
(data.set_index(['Rounds','Metrics'])
 .unstack(1)
 .droplevel(0,axis=1)
 .sort_index(1,ascending=False)
 .plot(figsize=(8,5), grid=True,kind='bar',legend=False))
```

output:

[image]

### UPDATE:

try:

```
data=(data.set_index(['Rounds','Metrics'])
 .unstack(1)
 .droplevel(0,axis=1)
 .reset_index())

fig,ax=plt.subplots(1,2,figsize=(8,5))
ax[0].bar(x=data['Rounds'],height=data['Score'])
ax[1].bar(x=data['Rounds'],height=data['Time'],color=['orange'])
ax[0].set_xlabel('Rounds')
ax[1].set_xlabel('Rounds')
ax[0].set_ylabel('Score')
ax[1].set_ylabel('Time')
ax[0].grid()
ax[1].grid()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Round should show time and score side by side, x axis should show 0, 1, 2 and y should display Metrics with time and score as hostograms; 2 separatte plots in one pic is also fine

Comment: it does not show which score is associated with which time

Comment: Update answer......kindly check if it is what you want?

Comment: you want to change the position of legend or want to remove the legend?

Comment: remove the legend

Comment: Updated answer......kindly check if it is what you want?

Comment: @Khaned If you remove this line `.sort_index(1,ascending=False)` from code then the order is changed so try removing if you want to change the order of columns in graph according to your need

Comment: I want to pivot the metrics column and show Time and score on different grids in the same plot. How is it possible?

Comment: @Khaned Btw that's is the different question from the current one...but anyway updated answer....Kindly have a look ***:)***

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using `matplotlib` module and `groupby()` function.

**Code**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

data = np.array([[0,'Time',27.390000],
                [0,'Score',0.027585],
                [1,'Time',47.390000],
                [1,'Score',0.23776],
                [2,'Time',65.390000],
                [2,'Score',0.44776],
                [3, 'Time', 80.390000],
                [3, 'Score', 10.44776]])

data = pd.DataFrame(data)
data.columns = ['Rounds','Metrics','WA_All_par_1']
data["WA_All_par_1"] = pd.to_numeric(data["WA_All_par_1"])
print(data)

data=data.groupby('Rounds')

x = data.nth(0).index
X_axis = np.arange(len(data.nth(1).index))

plt.bar(X_axis - 0.2, data.nth(0)['WA_All_par_1'], 0.4, label='Time')
plt.bar(X_axis + 0.2, data.nth(1)['WA_All_par_1'], 0.4, label='Score')
plt.xticks(X_axis, x)
plt.xlabel("Rounds")
plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

**Input**

```
  Rounds Metrics  WA_All_par_1
0      0    Time     27.390000
1      0   Score      0.027585
2      1    Time     47.390000
3      1   Score      0.237760
4      2    Time     65.390000
5      2   Score      0.447760
6      3    Time     80.390000
7      3   Score     10.447760
```

> Note: I added extra rows since your scores were too low to see

**Output**
[image]